# Compare content of two array

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I need to compare content for two array (source/target) of objects.

If an item in source does not exist in target, I should add item only to include.

If an item in source does exist in target, I should add item only to exclude.

Currently using ramda `R.differenceWith()` but I get an issue when target is empty.

I would to know if `differenceWith` fit the porpoise here, or I could use another functions. Please provide me an example thanks!

Notes: An answer even without using ramda is ok.

[Demo](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?%2F%2F%20source%0A%20%20const%20pathHash1%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20hash%3A%20%22c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20path%3A%20%22.%2Fsource%2Ffile1.txt%22%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20const%20pathHash2%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20hash%3A%20%22c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20path%3A%20%22.%2Fsource%2Ffile2.txt%22%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20const%20pathHash3%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20hash%3A%20%22eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20path%3A%20%22.%2Fsouce%2Ffile3.txt%22%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20target%0A%20%20const%20pathHash4%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20hash%3A%20%22eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20path%3A%20%22.%2Ftarget%2Ffile3.txt%22%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20works%0A%2F%2F%20const%20source%20%3D%20%5BpathHash1%2C%20pathHash2%2C%20pathHash3%5D%0A%2F%2F%20const%20target%20%3D%20%5BpathHash4%5D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20issue%0Aconst%20source%20%3D%20%5BpathHash1%2C%20pathHash2%2C%20pathHash3%5D%0Aconst%20target%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20result%20pathHash1%2C%20pathHash2%0Aconst%20resultInclude%20%3D%20R.differenceWith%28%28x%2Cy%29%3D%3E%20x.hash%20%3D%3D%3D%20y.hash%2C%20source%2C%20target%29%0Aconst%20resultExclude%3D%20R.differenceWith%28%28x%2Cy%29%3D%3E%20x.hash%20%21%3D%3D%20y.hash%2C%20source%2C%20target%29%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%27include%27%2CresultInclude.map%28x%3D%3Ex.hash%29%29%0Aconsole.log%28%27exclude%27%2CresultExclude.map%28x%3D%3Ex.hash%29%29%0A%0A%0A%0A)

```
// source
  const pathHash1 = {
    hash: "c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b",
    path: "./source/file1.txt"
  };
  const pathHash2 = {
    hash: "c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c",
    path: "./source/file2.txt"
  };
  const pathHash3 = {
    hash: "eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3",
    path: "./souce/file3.txt"
  };
  // target
  const pathHash4 = {
    hash: "eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3",
    path: "./target/file3.txt"
  };

// works
// const source = [pathHash1, pathHash2, pathHash3]
// const target = [pathHash4]

// does no work
const source = [pathHash1, pathHash2, pathHash3]
const target = []

// result pathHash1, pathHash2
const resultInclude = R.differenceWith((x,y)=> x.hash === y.hash, source, target)
const resultExclude= R.differenceWith((x,y)=> x.hash !== y.hash, source, target)

console.log('include',resultInclude.map(x=>x.hash))
console.log('exclude',resultExclude.map(x=>x.hash))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`R.innerJoin`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#innerJoin) for the exclude case:

```js
const getInclude = R.differenceWith(R.eqProps('hash'))
const getExclude = R.innerJoin(R.eqProps('hash'))

const pathHash1 = {hash: "c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b",path: "./source/file1.txt"},pathHash2 = {hash: "c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c",path: "./source/file2.txt"},pathHash3 = {hash: "eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3",path: "./souce/file3.txt"},pathHash4 = {hash: "eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3",path: "./target/file3.txt"}

const source1 = [pathHash1, pathHash2, pathHash3]
const target1 = [pathHash4]

const source2 = [pathHash1, pathHash2, pathHash3]
const target2 = []

const getHash = R.map(R.prop('hash'))

console.log('include1', getHash(getInclude(source1, target1)))
console.log('exclude1', getHash(getExclude(source1, target1)))

console.log('include2', getHash(getInclude(source2, target2)))
console.log('exclude2', getHash(getExclude(source2, target2)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla js you could consider using this version:

```
  const resultInclude = pathHashListSource.filter(x => !pathHashListTarget.find(y => y.hash === x.hash));
  const resultExclude = pathHashListSource.filter(x => pathHashListTarget.find(y => y.hash === x.hash));
```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. I really dig ramda, but this is the cleanest and least verbose solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `difference` instead of `differenceWith` for simple objects. If you want to find the common objects in both `source` and `target`, I'd suggest using `innerJoin`:

```js
const {difference, innerJoin, equals} = R;

const a = [{x: 1}, {y: 2}, {z: 3}];
const b = [{a: 0}, {x: 1}];

console.log(
  difference(a, b)
);

console.log(
  innerJoin(equals, a, b)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The result you get from [R.differenceWith()](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#differenceWith) is correct because the source of such a method is:

```
var differenceWith = _curry3(function differenceWith(pred, first, second) {
    var out = [];
    var idx = 0;
    var firstLen = first.length;
    while (idx < firstLen) {
            if (!_includesWith(pred, first[idx], second) && 
                !_includesWith(pred, first[idx], out)) {
                out.push(first[idx]);
            }
            idx += 1;
    }
    return out;
});
```

Like you can see the difference is computed using **_includesWith**. But, while the second array is empty the on going output array is going to be be filled (no duplicates).

```js
// source
const pathHash1 = {
    hash: "c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b",
    path: "./source/file1.txt"
};
const pathHash2 = {
    hash: "c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c",
    path: "./source/file2.txt"
};
const pathHash3 = {
    hash: "eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3",
    path: "./souce/file3.txt"
};
// target
const pathHash4 = {
    hash: "eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3",
    path: "./target/file3.txt"
};

// works
// const source = [pathHash1, pathHash2, pathHash3]
// const target = [pathHash4]

// issue
const source = [pathHash1, pathHash2, pathHash3]
const target = []

// result pathHash1, pathHash2
const resultInclude = R.differenceWith((x,y)=> x.hash === y.hash, source, target)
const resultExclude= R.differenceWith((x,y)=> x.hash !== y.hash, source, target)


console.log('include',resultInclude.map(x=>x.hash))
console.log('exclude',resultExclude.map(x=>x.hash))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@latest/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option here is to build up a native `Set` of the target hashes and use [`R.partition`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#partition) to split the source list into two lists depending on whether or not the hash exists in the `Set`.

```js
const source = [
  {
    hash: "c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b",
    path: "./source/file1.txt"
  },
  {
    hash: "c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c",
    path: "./source/file2.txt"
  },
  {
    hash: "eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3",
    path: "./souce/file3.txt"
  }
]

const target = [
  {
    hash: "eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3",
    path: "./target/file3.txt"
  }
]

////

const targetHashes =
  target.reduce((hashes, next) => hashes.add(next.hash), new Set)

const [resultExclude, resultInclude] =
  R.partition(x => targetHashes.has(x.hash), source)

////

console.log("resultInclude", resultInclude)
console.log("resultExclude", resultExclude)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```